# how to genrate keywords, hashtags or tags for a image with python?

Tags: python, keyword

I have seen it on Shutterstock or on many websites. if you upload an image with automatically generate suggested tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's commonly done using (Deep) Artificial Neural Networks (NNs). 
The idea is that you feed an image into a trained NN model and it will predict a classification of the entire image, detect objects present in the image, or even label regions inside the image. There's a lot of freedom in what can be achieved. Since good models are not easy to obtain (without large amounts of data and intense training resources), there exist pretrained models that can be finetuned by the user in order to make it work on your own particular dataset (unfortunately, these models are often somewhat overfit to the dataset they have been trained on such that finetuning is necessary most of the time). I think this [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/07/top-10-pretrained-models-get-started-deep-learning-part-1-computer-vision/) will point you further into the direction how these automatically suggested tags can be generated.